# Why were audiences led to believe that Mike Webster died from a taser gun?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, concussion

The 2015 film, [Concussion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322364/) tells the true story of Dr. Bennet Omalu uncovering the truth about brain damage in football players due to repeated head injuries.

The film focuses primarily on the Pittsburgh Steelers and former player and member of the Steelers,  [Mike Webster](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Webster).  The film depicts the physical and psychological problems that Mike Webster was suffering from before his death.

There is a scene in the film that shows Mike Webster sitting in the back of his pick up truck and using a taser gun on himself.  The film does not explain the reasoning behind this.  In actuality, he did this to himself so that he could knock himself out to [sleep](http://espn.go.com/nfl/news/story?id=1972285).

> Desperate for a few moments of peace from the acute pain, repeatedly
>   stunning himself, sometimes a dozen times, into unconsciousness with a
>   black Taser gun. "The only way he could get to sleep."

Immediately following the scene depicting Webster using a taser gun on himself, we see him lying in the morgue awaiting an autopsy.  This would lead audiences to believe that he died from a taser gun and that it was suicide.

Mike Webster was not a household name.  Only die hard NFL fans and Pittsburgh Steeler fans knew who he was and how he actually died.  Mike Webster died at a Pittsburgh [hospital](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/09/25/sports/mike-webster-50-dies-troubled-football-hall-of-famer.html).

**Is there a reason why filmmakers chose to imply that Mike Webster died from a self-inflicted taser gun injury?**

After researching this film, it appears that most of the facts are correct.  Of course, there will be certain facts that are over dramatized for entertainment purposes.  The cause of death of Mike Webster seemed an important part of the story, so **is there any evidence that filmmakers believed that Mike Webster died in this way?**

Comment: What are these Steelers of which you speak? Never heard of them before :-P

Comment: Your link does not disprove that he died as a result of a taser shot. The hospital refused to reveal his cause of death publicly. If this was something he had to do daily to get any sleep, it would almost certainly be a contributing factor to his heart health. Maybe the filmakers felt that implying he died due to taser puts the cause, ultimately, down to his brain damage.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link to about Webster says that "Webster's cause of death has not been released."

I obviously have no special insight into what the cause of his death was, but it was at an unusually young age (50), and I can't imagine tasing himself did any favors to his health.  I have not seen *Concussion*, but based on your description, it sounds like a reasonably accurate depiction based on what we know about Webster and the very few facts we have about his death.